# TinyMCE Source Code plugin removing text between anchor tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to make an anchor tag link with text...so when i edit the source code and enter something like

```html
<a id="downloadButton" data-document="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Download Brochure</a>
```

it automatically changes it to

```html
<a id="downloadButton" data-document="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"></a>Download Brochure
```

It works if i remove the id, but i cant do that because i need that id, another solution is to add `href="#downloadButton"` but i wold like to do it without it

i added

```
valid_children: "+a[div | i | span | img | p | ul | ol | li | h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h5 | h6 | #text]",
```

in the `tinymce.init` part but that didn't help at all.

Is there a way to solve this or do i need to add the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE views anchors without an `href` as a bookmark and won't allow text inside the anchor tag.  This is something the internal parser in TinyMCE manages so there is no way around this behavior.

If you want to suggest to the developers that this behavior should change I would suggest you open an issue on the TinyMCE GitHub issue tracker:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar thing but it didn't work, at the end, I did it like this:

```
<h2><a id="HTML" class="h2 text-light" href="#">HTML</a></h2>
```

and then javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(anchor) {
  if (anchor.getAttribute('href') === "#"){
    anchor.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    anchor.style.textDecoration = "none";
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  };
});
```

this way TinyMCE is letting me save the page without moving text from the anchor tag + the text looks like usual (not underlined) + when I click on it nothing will happen.